# Specifying the image of a set of states under the action of a channel

Tags: quantum-state, linear-algebra, quantum-operation

I have a generic channel $\mathcal{N}$ acting on a subspace of states defined on a $d$-dimensional Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}$. I am trying to make a statement about the dimension of the image of that subspace under the action of $\mathcal{N}$. My question is, is there a way to describe the image in terms of a linear span in a way that also demonstrates that the image is a subset of states?

More specifically: Let $\text{D}(\mathcal{H})$ be the set of density operators on $\mathcal{H}$. Then, fix $k < d$ and fix an orthonormal basis $\{|i\rangle\}_{i=1}^d$ in order to define $\text{D}_k $ as the set of states with support on the first $k$ elements of that basis:
\begin{equation}
\text{D}_k  = \Bigl\{\rho: \rho = \sum_{i,j=1}^k \rho_{ij} |i\rangle \langle j|;\,\, \rho \geq 0;\,\, \text{Tr}(\rho)=1 \Bigr\}. \tag{1}
\end{equation}
If $\mathcal{N}(\text{D}_k)$ denotes the image of $\text{D}_k$ under the action of $\mathcal{N}$, then we have
$$\mathcal{N}(\text{D}_k) \subseteq \text{span}\left\{\mathcal{N}(|i\rangle \langle j|)\right\}_{i,j=1}^k. \tag{2}
$$
However, the RHS of this equation by itself doesn't make a clear statement about the dimensionality of the image. For instance, a span written like this could contain the maximum number of linearly independent components while containing no states at all. The only knowledge we have that this set contains states is that $\mathcal{N}$ is CPTP and that the pre-image of the set contains states.

Is there a way to describe this image in such a way that

1. It is clear that the image is a subset of states, and
2. that subset has strictly lower *dimensionality* than the image of $\text{D}(\mathcal{H})$ for $k < d$?

---

For reference, this is straightforward when we consider a subset of pure states and unitary maps (where it is also clearer what is meant by dimensionality). I'm just having trouble extending the notation/intuition to operators:

Let $\text{S}(\mathcal{H})$ be the set of pure states defined on $\mathcal{H}$. Again fix $k <d$ and orthonormal basis $\{|i\rangle\}_{i=1}^d$ and define the set of pure states with support on the first $k$ elements of that basis:
\begin{equation}
\text{S}_k := \Bigl\{ |\psi\rangle: |\psi\rangle = \sum_{i=1}^k \psi_i |i\rangle; \,\, \psi_i \in \mathbb{C};\,\, \lVert|\psi\rangle \rVert = 1\Bigr\} \tag{3}
\end{equation}
Now for any fixed unitary $U$ acting on $\mathcal{H}$, the image of $\text{S}_k$ under $U$ is restricted to a $k$-dimensional subspace of states in $\mathcal{H}$:
\begin{align}
U(\text{S}_k) &:= \Bigl\{ U|\psi\rangle: |\psi\rangle \in \text{S}_k\Bigr\}\tag{4a}
\\&=\Bigl\{|\psi\rangle: |\psi\rangle = \sum_{i=1}^k \psi_i |u_i\rangle; \,\, \psi_i \in \mathbb{C};\,\, \lVert|\psi\rangle \rVert = 1\Bigr\} \tag{4b}
\\&\subset \text{span}\left(\{|u_i\rangle\}_{i=1}^k\} \right) \tag{4c}
\end{align}
where $|u_i\rangle := U|i\rangle$. This works because of linearity and unitarity (specifically preservation of inner product under $U$). This clearly indicates that the image of $S_k$  does itself contain states (4b) and that the dimension of the image is at most $k < d$ (4c, the dimension of the linear span). For my purposes the upper bound on dimensionality is fine, I don't mind that its an equality in this case.